# Do we need a Sub-Answers feature?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

In my experience as a user of stack exchange sites, I have seen that some users who try to answer question want to complete an existing answer to a question or they want to share their own experience related to some points of an existing answer. Also, some users want to develop or extend the existing feature of an answer however, they do not really want to separately post an answer to a question. Their posts are not as complete as answers but they are not comments too. These are something between a complete answer and a comment to it.

These type of answers are usually followed by a structure like: `the answer by user A perfectly answers this question, but I want to add my own experience....` or some other who want to complete an existing answer and build their answers upon an existing point (such as a programming code) post answers like: `I am making this program code upon user A's answer and want to add this minor feature to it...`.

So, we see that some answers are built upon existing answers to questions.

I think that the websites lack a feature like posting **Sub-Answers** which may allow the users to post answers as a sub category or sub-post to existing answers. By having this feature, these answers are organized under the answer which they are completing or extending it. Also, when the question is opened and the answers are sorted by number of votes or newest answer, the answers and their sub-answers are shown together so other users may not lose the connection between answers.

Here is a the sample structure of this feature:

```
Question's Title
Question's Text

Answer 1
Comments on Answer 1

Answer 2
Comments on Answer 2

     Sub-Answer 2-1
     Comments on Sub-Answer 2-1

     Sub-Answer 2-2
     Comments on Sub-Answer 2-2
```

Comment: This'd make Q&A pages into forum threads. Instead of partial answers, post proper answers instead.

Comment: Downvotes to my first post on meta. Too sad :-(... I just wanted to propose something to improve the website.

Comment: See the [Meta FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-exchange-work/47635#47635); you posted a feature request and people are voting on that request.

Answer (score 13):

Stack Exchange was **designed to *avoid* a lot of the old forum-style problems** — and the number one problem on that *hit list* was where someone would ask a question, and the best answer was **finally** derived somewhere near the bottom of page 18.

Stack Exchange was designed to fix all that. When someone posts a question, the voting and wiki-style editing helps assure that the best answer rises to the top. Folks shouldn't *have* to read through a lot of anecdotes and addendum to find the complete answer. "Sub-answers" sends us back in that direction where someone is always saying, *"but wait, there's more…"* Folks will always want to "complete the answer" and to "extend the answer" (and to just plain ol' opine and comment on it). And before you know it, the best answer *isn't* first; it's buried somewhere deep in the middle of the discussion.

Stack Exchange is based on a wiki-style system of adding and editing. If you have a better answer, you should add it and let the community vote. But if you can improve on an *existing* answer, you should edit and improve what has already been written. Folks have to get over that aversion to "touching someone else's work."

That is how Stack Exchange is designed.

Answer (score 5):

No. Stack Exchange sites aren't forums and they are good the way they are.

The strongest point of the SE network is that it is very clear and only contains useful information. Comments are stripped as much as possible, answers are to the point. Wonderful!

If this feature gets implemented, SE will lose its strongest point. **If it isn't an answer, nor a constructive comment, it doesn't belong here.**

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues here I think, none of which really need any additional functionality to handle because of the functionality already available and what I believe to be a misunderstanding or lack of familiarity with the way Stack Exchange works. Stack Exchange is *not* a forum so discussion should be minimized. Each question should contain one question and any related questions should be linked together.

> the answer by user A perfectly answers this question, but I want to add my own experience....

This is handled by posting an additional answer, if you have an alternative method of doing something - even if the existing answers are valid - you post it as your own answer.

> I am making this program code upon user A's answer and want to add this minor feature to it...

This is a new question, if you have an additional question as a result of an answer, post a new question, link it back to the answer you're referencing.

> Any other scenario

Comments - where you're not posting a full answer but have a little more to add to the existing answer. You could also edit it in, if it fits with the existing answer.

Comment: "discussion should be minimized". I think it belongs in chat. The site itself isn't meant for discussions.

Comment: About your second point, some users add a small part to a code (for instance a LaTeX code) in an answer; or some users complete an answer and edit some parts of a proposed answer and answer their own question. This is not about posting a new question.

Comment: The "question" is what the original poster posted. Any questions that weren't posted in the "question" part of the page are *not* questions that are being dealt with - these need to be their own questions. If the original poster edited their "question" and now the answers need updating, then update the existing answers rather than posting a new one.

Answer (score 2):

What you propose is *mostly* supported. Your subanswers are really answers that build upon other answers. **You can already do this.** You can post a new answer in which you acknowledge that this answer builds upon user X answer's and provide a link to that answer. And since you are posting a new answer, it gets its own comments.

The only thing the SE software does not support right now is showing any kind of genetic relationship between answers. I do not think there is enough value in this feature to support the request here.

Comment: I think this can lead to convoluted Q&A, and that it is usually better to only answer one question and suggest the remainder be asked as new questions.